# Get headers Ajax Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to get the header value "Date" like this but it gives:

```
xhr.getResponseHeader is not a function
```

I see the response header in firebug and it exists :S

Maybe no JQuery support? Can this be done in JavaScript instead maybe? must work, I can see the headers...

Code:

```
function ajaxDate(myUrl){   
var res;    
var ajaxCall=$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: myUrl,
    crossDomain: true,
        async: false,
        cache: false
    }).always(function(output, status, xhr) {
            //alert(xhr.getResponseHeader("MyCookie"));
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(output);
        console.log(status);
    res=xhr.getResponseHeader('Date');
        });
    return res;
}
```

---

Debug dump from firebug, url: www.google.se:

200 OK  92ms    jquery.min.js (line 5)

Response Headers

```
Alternate-Protocol  80:quic
Cache-Control   private, max-age=0
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Fri, 09 Aug 2013 00:57:43 GMT
Expires -1
P3P CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Server  gws
Set-Cookie  PREF=ID=e6503cda76a:FF=0:TM=1376009863:LM=1376009863:S=pByclnZqvnZs2k5S; expires=Sun, 09-Aug-2015 00:57:43 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.se, expires=Sat, 08-Feb-2014 00:57:43 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.se; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
x-frame-options SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection    1; mode=block
```

Request Headers

```
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Host    www.google.se
Origin  http://localhost/
Referer http://localhost/
User-Agent  ....
```

console.log(xhr)

```
[Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js :: .send :: line 5" data: no] { name="NS_ERROR_FAILURE", message="Failure", result=2147500037, more...}
auto.js (line 52)
```

console.log(output)

```
Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="[Exception... "Failure"...d :: line 5" data: no]"}
auto.js (line 53)
```

console.log(status)

```
error
```

Comment: [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) report 2 different signatures for `.always`, the jquery xhr object being either the 1st or the 3rd argument - have you tried `.always(function(xhr, status, output)` ?

Comment: @PHPglue: you don't. see the [page in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), specifically the deprecation notice. `.always` replaces `.complete` as the callback to be processed after completion of the ajax request regardless of its result.

Comment: success is depricated? Tested with success and there was no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of always is

```
.always(function(data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown) { });
```

if mapped to your method

```
.always(function(output, status, xhr) {
```

This line

```
res=xhr.getResponseHeader('Date'); // If response is a success
```

supposed to be

```
res=output.getResponseHeader('Date'); // if response fails
```

Looks like your method is failing which maps the same method to `errorThrown`

Instead you can write up a separate `fail` method to handle it or make a small change in the syntax.

```
res= output.getResponseHeader ? output.getResponseHeader.get('Date')
                              : xhr.getResponseHeader.get('Date')
```

Comment: I will test this, sound very nice

Comment: My method is failing but with your solution it instead gives me TypeError: output.getResponseHeader.get is not a function

Comment: Can you try putting a debug point inside that callback and inspect the arguments

Comment: The console.log(output) shows me that there is a method to get all response headers getAllResponseHeaders(), however this returns an empty string :/

Comment: Maybe that object is only available when your ajax fails

Comment: using fail instead of always still gives me an empty string response for getAllResponseHeaders()

Comment: hmm.. Then I am not completely sure wat's going on there

Comment: okey, its so wired:S I can see the headers in firebug:/ Thanks for your help:)

Comment: @DavidMerged.. Glad to have helped :)